# Macbook Pro only mirrors 2nd/3rd monitor (even with it unchecked)

Tags: macos, display, screen, hdmi, dual-screen

I have a Macbook Pro with a dongle charger via USB C that has 2 HDMI Ports.

I have two monitors plugged in and they are both displaying, however only one is showing up under the Display System Preferences.

Both monitors are on but the 3rd monitor is not showing up under Arrangement even after tying "Detect Windows". It is ONLY mirroring the second/third monitor.

I've tried using a different dongle with a separate HDMI port hoping that would help, but am beyond stumped at this point.

[image: 3rd monitor is on but only displaying as a mirror.]

Comment: Your 'directions' seem very confused. Signals go **from** the computer **to** the display. You need to describe your connections & cables in that manner to save confusion.

Comment: sorry @Tetsujin added more clarity, appreciate any help!